# Firebase DataSnapshot retrieves deleted/non-existing nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am using Flutter as frontend mobile framework and Firebase realtime database as backend. I am trying to count the number of clicks of a particular component for which I get the recent click count from firebase and increment it by 1 and save it back. It is working fine. The issue here is when I try to reset the count directly in firebase, the DataSnapshot in dart receives the old count. I even deleted the node, but it still retrieves the non null recent count. Below is my code.

```
_buttonClicked() async {
   DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child('analitics')
    .child('buttonclicks');
   ref.keepSynced(true);
   ref.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
    if (snap.value == null) {
      ref.set(
        {'count': 1},
      );
    } else {
      AnaliticsModel count = AnaliticsModel.fromSnapshot(snap);
      int tempcount = count.count;
      tempcount += 1;
      ref.update(
        {'count': tempcount},
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Firebase database works offline too. So, your app must be fetching from the local db. You may try it by setting `persistenceEnabled = false.`

Comment: is there any way to turn off offline db?

Comment: You may check [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) and change it to flutter.

Comment: Great. I added `keepSynced(true)` below the database reference and it worked. Thanks much.